# how to make the String formatted from a date Final?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to implement a date to my newly created note the problem is that it is updating and doesn't keep the first value

```
  var now = new DateTime.now();
  var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd' + ' At ' + 'H:m');
  String date;`
  date = formatter.format(now);
```

Comment: what do you mean it is updating and doesn't keep the first value?

Comment: yes, for example i have created the note at 12:00, it will keep updating 12:01, 12:02, 12:03 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have added the code at wrong place. The place you have added the code may be refreshing again and again. Debug it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val myRunnableThread = CountDownRunner()
    var myThread = Thread(myRunnableThread)
    myThread.start()

}
fun doWork() {
    runOnUiThread {
        try {
            val dt = Date()

            var formatter = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a")
            tvTime.text = formatter.format(dt)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }
}


internal inner class CountDownRunner : Runnable {
    // @Override
    override fun run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) {
            try {
                doWork()
                Thread.sleep(1000) // Pause of 1 Second
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to make sure that you get the current time once and keep it without updating it later. For that, you can wrap your code with the following condition:

```
if (now == null) {
    now = new DateTime.now();
    ...
}
```

this will only get the current time once when your code runs for the first time and it will ignore it going forward. If you want the value to persist after your activity is destroyed/fragment is replaced, consider storing teh value on the shared preferences or some other data structure of your choice. When you first create the activity/fragment check whether it has a value or then leave it null.

Answer (score 0):

i think your code is setting the date on every setState you are doing and for this reason the time is changing. So why not setting this code in the `initState`

so in your `State` class

```
String date;
@override
  void initState() {
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd' + ' At ' + 'H:m');
    date = formatter.format(now);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: i fixed it now, i was placing inside the widget itself that refresh each time getting it out solved it, thank you